# Add-on Help Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, add-on

Is there a way to create a free unlisted add-on for an individual account (non-company account) I just need it so every time a spreadsheet is copied I don't have to authorize it.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that to create an add-on for internal use is only available for Google Workspace accounts as the project would need to be associated to an organization, otherwise as an end user you only have the option to set it up as `External` but have the add-on published as `Unlisted`. This way only the users who have the direct link would have access to see and install your add-on.

According to Google's documentation:

> If you choose to publish as Unlisted, the app listing won't show in browse or search results. Users can only access the app’s store page with the direct URL.

#### References:

- [Setting up your OAuth consent screen - User type](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615#user-type&zippy=%2Cinternal)
- [App visibility](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk#app_visibility)

Comment: I attached it to an organization and it still doesn’t work

Comment: Did you create the project using a Google Workspace account? @retter4242

Comment: Can you also share the App visibility section from the App Configuration part of the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK of your project?

Comment: @retter4242 What you're trying to achieve is very interesting, where you able to publish the app using the info that Fernando shared? See: [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)